# how to only display 2 spaces after the decimal in c#

Tags: c#, crash, decimal

So I have to make a BMI calculator for class but I just need some help with a couple things.

1. When I run my program, put in 2 values then calculate, it displays the right answer but there is like 8 digits after the decimal.
2. If I put any input other than numbers it crashes my program, how do i fix this?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void weightTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double BMI = 0;
        double weight = 0;
        double height = 0;
        height = Double.Parse(heightTxt.Text);
        weight = Double.Parse(weightTxt.Text);
        // declaring and assigning 
        if (weight > 300 || weight < 10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid input.");

        }
        if (height > 2.2 || height < 0.2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid input.");
        }

        // checking that values meet parameters
        BMI = weight / (height * height);
        string result = Convert.ToString(BMI);
        resultLbl.Text = "Your BMI is : " + result;
```

Comment: `string result = BMI.ToString("#.##");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the problem of crashing on non-numeric input, you can use Double.TryParse instead of Double.Parse:

```
if (!Double.TryParse(heightTxt.Text, out height)) {
    MessageBox.Show("Not a valid input.");
    return;
}
```

To address the problem of displaying to 2 decimal places, use BMI.ToString("#.##") as others have commented

Comment: This worked but i'm not sure why LOL Thanks, ill look into the documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
        double weight = 0;
        double height = 0;

        if (Double.TryParse(weightTxt.Text, out weight) && Double.TryParse(heightTxt.Text, out height)) {
            if (weight > 300 || weight < 10 || height > 2.2 || height < 0.2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid input.");
            }

            double BMI = weight / (height * height);

            /*Two ways for converting to two didges:*/

            // 1.

            // Round to two didgets
            double result = Math.Round(BMI, 2);
            // convert result to string
            string resultString = Convert.ToString(result);

            // 2.
            string resultString = BMI.ToString("#.##")               
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Boy if there was a nickel for every homework on stackoverflow.

```
            double BMI = 0;
            double weight = 0;
            double height = 0;

            //use try parse to test if the value is convertable
            if (!Decimal.TryParse(heightTxt.Text,out height))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid input.");
                return;
            }

            if (!Decimal.TryParse(weightTxt.Text, out weight))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid input.");
                return;
            }

            // declaring and assigning 
            if (weight > 300 || weight < 10)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid input.");
                //return so the method dosnt try to do the rest of the code
                return;

            }
            if (height > 2.2 || height < 0.2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not a valid input.");
                return;
            }

            BMI = weight / (height * height);
            //this is how you format the nuumber to two decimal places
            string result = BMI.ToString("#.##");
            resultLbl.Text = "Your BMI is : " + result;
```